# Hplip network printer setup cannot find printer (HP Officejet Pro 8620)

Tags: networking, hp, scanner, hplip

I have a **HP Officejet Pro 8620** printer and I am trying to setup network scan with it but the `hp-setup` tool claims it cannot find the printer. However the printer is connected to the network and I can already print with it from the same Ubuntu computer.

I have setup the machine with **wifi only** (no USB or ethernet). I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (with the Gnome Desktop) and I have gone to "System Settings" -> Printers and added the HP printer there, everything worked and printing works well. I can also open the website of the printer by entering the IP address of the printer into the web browser (I used that to update the Printer Firmware already).

Now I wanted to setup scanning so I can use it to scan over the network, but that does not work:

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.14.3)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) [...]
[...]

Searching... (bus=net, timeout=5, ttl=4, search=(None) desc=0, method=slp)
error: No devices found on bus: net
Searching... (bus=net, timeout=5, ttl=4, search=(None) desc=0, method=slp)
error: No devices found on bus: net
```

So far I have run `sudo hp-setup` from the console, then choose Network/Ethernet/Wireless network and then next. I even tried the other option and also I tried entering an IP address under advanced options.
[image]

I always get the above message and then end up at this screen:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to install the latest version of `hplip` from http://hplipopensource.com the details to it can be found in the [release notes](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/release_notes.html#id4)

Especially this section:

**HPLIP 3.14.4 - This release has the following changes:**
Added Support for the Following New Printers:
[...]
- HP OfficeJet Pro 8620 e-All-in-One Printer
[...]
Added support for the following new Distro's:
- Ubuntu 14.04 Beta

Comment: I was struggling with that issue for some time. The printer was connected correctly to the network but hp-setup did not find it. Finally I found out that SNMP was disabled on the printer. After I enabled it the hp-setup worked perfectly. The printer is HP LaserJet 100 color MFP M172nw.

Comment: Same version of hplip - everything is enabled on the printer (and is so by default) - so no joy. Just plug in the USB. Sad.

Comment: If this solved your issue, can you accept this answer?